# How to get the clean main text body of HTML pages with different templates

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a collection of HTML pages from different websites with various templates and I want to get the clean main body text of these pages. Since there are too many pages and there is always a chance new pages with different templates will be added to the collection, I can't go and check pages one by one and check what tags contain the main body text of a page in an HTML page so that I can remove extra tags and retrieve the main body of an article in a page (I mean I can but we all agree that it will be super time-consuming and boring!).

Currently, I am using the following two methods to clean the HTML pages and retrieve the main text body from them:

```
def tag_visible(element):
    blacklist = ['[document]', 'noscript', 'header', 'html', 'meta', 'head', 'input', 'script', 'style', 'title']
    if element.parent.name in blacklist:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html_v1(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)
```

**What is the problem?** even though these methods help me get a clean main body of HTML pages in a fair number of cases, there is always a chance some tags are not going to be detected by these methods for some pages with a different template and I may end up with some text from the menu bar or some other irrelevant parts of an HTML page. *Why is this problematic?* because in the next step I need to build some models based on the main body text of the content of these HTML files and noises like what I mentioned may hurt the models.

Any idea how I can deal with such a situation?

Comment: Maybe you could create a function that removes any potential noisy tags from your soup object, eg <a> <td> etc and keep only the ones that could be the main text like <p> etc. You could also work on the length of texts. Usually main body texts are lengthier than all the rest in the page

Answer (score 0):

### How about using BeautifulSoup´s `get_text()` method

If I understand your question correctly this would be a very simple approach getting your goal to return human-readable text from the `document` or `<body>`

**Plain `get_text()` method**

`get_text()` method will return all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string.

```
soup.body.get_text()
```

Problem could be that there will still occurre some noisy characters. But good news, there is an solution.

**Get rid of the noisy parts**

To strip that noise just add `strip=True` to the method and you will get a propper result with just this one line:

```
soup.body.get_text(strip=True)
```

**What you should be aware**

If there is some `code` represented as text as in this post it would not be stripped automatically, but be fair there is no one fits all solution. The approach is simply based on your question and could be one module of your data cleaning process, may followed by `regex` or `nltk`...

**Example:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696781/how-to-get-the-clean-main-text-body-of-html-pages-with-different-templates"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
soup.body.get_text(strip=True)
```

**Output**

```
Stack OverflowAboutProductsFor TeamsStack OverflowPublic questions & answersStack Overflow for TeamsWhere developers & technologists share private knowledge with coworkersJobsProgramming & related technical career opportunitiesTalentRecruit tech talent & build your employer brandAdvertisingReach developers & technologists worldwideAbout the companyLoading…Log inSign upcurrent communityStack OverflowhelpchatMeta Stack Overflowyour communitiesSign uporlog into customize your list.more stack exchange communitiescompany blogJoin Stack Overflowto learn, share knowledge, and build your career.Sign up with emailSign upSign up with GoogleSign up with GitHubSign up with FacebookHomePublicStack OverflowTagsUsersFind a JobJobsCompaniesTeamsWhat’s this?Free 30 Day TrialTeamsQ&A for WorkStack Overflow for Teams is a private, secure spot for you and\r\n                            your coworkers to find and share information.Learn moreHow to get the clean main text body of HTML pages with different templatesAsk QuestionAskedtodayActivetodayViewed16 times01I have a collection of HTML pages from different websites with various templates and I want to get the clean main body text of these pages. Since there are too many pages and there is always a chance new pages with different templates will be added to the collection, I can\'t go and check pages one by one and check what tags contain the main body text of a page in an HTML page so that I can remove extra tags and retrieve the main body of an article in a page (I mean I can but we all agree that it will be super time-consuming and boring!).Currently, I am using the following two methods to clean the HTML pages and retrieve the main text body from them:def tag_visible(element):\n    blacklist = [\'[document]\', \'noscript\', \'header\', \'html\', \'meta\', \'head\', \'input\', \'script\', \'style\', \'title\']\n    if element.parent.name in blacklist:\n        return False\n    if isinstance(element, Comment):\n        return False\n    return True\n\n\ndef text_from_html_v1(body):\n    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, \'html.parser\')\n    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)\n    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)\n    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)What is the problem?
```